# How do I make a certain keyboard command system wide?

Tags: keyboard

I'm using WireTap to record some documentary while I need to frequently make cue mark command (Command-Shift-T).

And the way I do is first use Command-Tab to switch to Wire Tap and hit Command-Shift-T, and then switch back to the player which is very annoying.

Is there a way to make the command system wide?

Answer (score 1):

**[Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/)** is a very powerful and easy to use keyboard macro app. If you want a multi-step process available everywhere on your Mac you can't do much better.

By "multi-step process" I mean, to use your example, no matter what app I'm using right now, pressing a certain key combination performs these steps.

1. Quickly switch to the Wire Tap app.
2. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> in the Wire Tap app.
3. Quickly switch back to whatever app you were previously in.

This all happens so quickly that you can barely tell any app switching occurred.

I use it to start and stop my time tracking app at the press of a keystroke, for instance, as well as ensuring that <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> zooms in no matter what graphics app I'm using and <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> zooms out.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [Spark.](http://www.shadowlab.org/Software/spark.php) It's a great (free!!) hot key manager for OS X. I have found it to be very useful. I don't exactly understand what you want to make system wide, but if you'll edit your question to clarify what you mean, I can give you more help with setting up the hot keys.